# Can I use the union of two columns values in Excel as row labels in a Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table:

<kbd>Name</kbd><kbd>Color 1</kbd><kbd>Color 2</kbd>
<kbd>John</kbd><kbd>Red</kbd><kbd>Green</kbd>
<kbd>Paul</kbd><kbd>Red</kbd><kbd>Yellow</kbd>
<kbd>Mary</kbd><kbd>Yellow</kbd><kbd>Blue</kbd>
<kbd>Sarah</kbd><kbd>Pink</kbd><kbd>Yellow</kbd>

and I would like to create the following table (order non important) from that:

<kbd>Color</kbd><kbd>Times requested</kbd>
<kbd>Red</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>Green</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>Yellow</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>Blue</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>Pink</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

Is there a way to do that with Pivot tables or any other trick?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Select `Multiple consolidation ranges`. Click `Next`.

[image]

3. Select `Create a single page field for me`. Click `Next`.
4. Select all your data *including* headers and your names. Click `Next`.

[image]

5. Decide where you want your new table. Click `Finish`.
6. Uncheck `Row`, `Column`, `Value` and `Page1`. Drag `Value` into both `Rows` and `Values`.
7. Rename your headers as required, and if you wish to remove `Grand Total` just right click it and `Remove Grand Total`.

[image]

Comment: This works, but what really happened? How did it know what to combine into Value? Also, the 'Name' Field seems to be gone?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited list of possible colour values, then you can do this with the [`COUNTIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) function, no pivot tables required.

If your colours are in cells B2 to C5, `=COUNTIF($B$2:$C$5,"Red")` will count how many times 'Red' appeared.  If you've got lots of colours to count, replace `"Red"` with a cell reference so you can cut'n'paste the formula down your results table.  (e.g. `=COUNTIF($B$2:$C$5,E1)` will count how many times the contents of cell E1 appears in the range).

The disadvantage of this is that you do have to list out all the colours you want counted.  If you want to automatically generate the list of unique items too, then a pivot table is the way to go.